# How to pick data from array and create a single Object from it?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to create a single object from an array of objects. Please refer the code provided.

Here's the input array

```
let queryArr = [
  {
    query: {
        filter: {
          term: {
            search: 'complete',
          }
        }
    }
  },
  {
    query: {
        notFilter: {
          term: {
            search: 'failed',
          }
        }
    }
  },
  {
    query: {
      bool: {
          term: {
            search: 'complete',
          }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The expected output

```
let oneQuery = {query: {
      bool: { ... },
      filter: { ... },
      notFilter: { ... } // data from respective array object key
    }};
```

The function I wrote

```
function createQuery(arr){
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(Object.keys(arr[i].query === 'bool')){
       oneQuery.query.bool = arr[i].query.bool;
    }
    if(Object.keys(arr[i].query === 'filter')){
       oneQuery.query.filter = arr[i].query.filter;
    }
    if(Object.keys(arr[i].query === 'notFilter')){
       oneQuery.query.notFilter = arr[i].query.notFilter;
    }
  }
  return oneQuery;
}
createQuery(queryArr);
```

The output I'm getting:

```
query: {
   bool: { ... },
   filter: undefined,
   notFilter: undefined
}
```

I don't get what I'm doing wrong here. A solution using reduce or map will be preferred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get an array with the contents of each `query` property, then [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to combine to a single object:

```js
const queryArr = [{"query":{"filter":{"term":{"search":"complete"}}}},{"query":{"notFilter":{"term":{"search":"failed"}}}},{"query":{"bool":{"term":{"search":"complete"}}}}];

const createQuery = (arr) => ({ 
  query: Object.assign({}, ...queryArr.map(({ query }) => query)) 
});

console.log(createQuery(queryArr));
```

To fix your code, initialize the query item, and get the 1st key from each item in the array - `arr[i].query)[0]`:

```js
const queryArr = [{"query":{"filter":{"term":{"search":"complete"}}}},{"query":{"notFilter":{"term":{"search":"failed"}}}},{"query":{"bool":{"term":{"search":"complete"}}}}]


function createQuery(arr){
  const oneQuery = { query: {} };

  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(Object.keys(arr[i].query)[0] === 'bool'){
       oneQuery.query.bool = arr[i].query.bool;
    }
    if(Object.keys(arr[i].query)[0] === 'filter'){
       oneQuery.query.filter = arr[i].query.filter;
    }
    if(Object.keys(arr[i].query)[0] === 'notFilter'){
       oneQuery.query.notFilter = arr[i].query.notFilter;
    }
  }
  return oneQuery;
}
console.log(createQuery(queryArr));
```

Answer (score 1):

You problem seems to be this line

```
Object.keys(arr[i].query === 'filter')
```

This evaluates to `Object.keys(true)` or `Object.keys(false)`

Use `reduce`

```
queryArr.reduce( (acc, c) => ( 
   acc[ Object.keys(c.query)[0] ] = Object.values(c.query)[0],  //set the first key and value to accumulator
   acc ), //return the accumulator 
{}); //initialize accumulator to {}
```